# C#. Сколько недель затрагивается между двумя датами?

Tags: c#

Использовал раньше формулу

```
double weeks = (Model.MaxDate - Model.MinDate).Value.TotalDays / 7;
```

А потом просто округлял в большую сторону, но чуть позже возник парадокс - если мы выберем промежуток дат между `12.11.2020` до `17.11.2020` - то по формуле это одна неделя(дней то `<= 7`), а по реальному времени - недели две.

Каким образом это можно учесть и исправить?
На вход могу подавать любые даты, их разница только в том что максимальное значение всегда больше минимального, хотя бы на день( т.е. `MIN = 12.11.2020` - `MAX` - не может быть меньше `13.11.2020`)

Comment: Откуда там недели две по реальному времени?

Comment: @yolosora 12 число - ЧТ (эта неделя). 17 число - ВТ (уже другая).
Выходит что интервал между датами затрагивает обе недели

Answer (score 2):

Вижу, что вы уже нашли себе решение пока я писал, что я имел ввиду, но уж допишу, хотя решение получается более громоздкое.

Вы можете определить для любой даты какой у неё номер недели, например:

```
var currentDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 12);
var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
var weekNum = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(currentDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

Выведет 46тую неделю для указанной выше даты.

Считайте для вашего интервала в какие недели попадают ваши даты (например: 46тая, 46тая, 47мая) и находите сколько разных недель попало в ваш интервал.

Вот так:

```
private int PlacedWeeks(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
    var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

    var weeks = new List<int>();

    var currentDate = start;

    while (currentDate < finish)
    {
        weeks.Add(calendar.GetWeekOfYear(currentDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday));
        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    return weeks.Distinct().Count();
}
```

По идее, логичнее было бы брать HashSet:

```
private int PlacedWeeks(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
    var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

    var weeks = new HashSet<int>();

    var currentDate = start;

    while (currentDate < finish)
    {
        weeks.Add(calendar.GetWeekOfYear(currentDate, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday));
        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    return weeks.Count();
}
```

Ну или сделать в linq:

```
private int PlacedWeeks(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
    var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

    var sp = finish - start;
    
    return Enumerable.Range(0, sp.Days)
                     .Select(x => calendar.GetWeekOfYear(start.AddDays(x), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
                     .Distinct()
                     .Count();
}
```

Все варианты дают для ваших дат то, что вы просили:

```
var d1 = new DateTime(2020, 11, 12);
var d2 = new DateTime(2020, 11, 20);

PlacedWeeks(d1, d2).Dump();
```

PS Пока писал - понял, что можно было просто взять разницу номеров недель для крайних точек интевала:

```
private int PlacedWeeks(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
    var calendar = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

    var startWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(start, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    var finishWeek = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(finish, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    
    return finishWeek - startWeek + 1;
}
```

Comment: Мммм... разницу номеров недель можно брать только при условии, что недели находятся в одном году, иначе вычитая из первой недели пятьдесят вторую можно получить неожиданный результат. Так что хотя вариант с подсчётом уникальных недель и кажется избыточным -- всё же если нужна универсальность лучше заложиться на него.

Comment: Или дополнить `if (startWeek > finishWeek ) return finishWeek  - finishWeek + startWeek +1`; и вообще все мои варианты предполагают, что интервал не располагается более чем в двух разных годах.

Comment: Довольно интересный способ) Я что то похожее находил перед тем, как начал изменять свою формулу сегодня, а если точнее - `calendar.GetWeekOfYear(finish, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);` 
Но мне он показался немного перемудренным подходом, хотя мб он может быть лучше, тут не проверял.
Пример написанный мною я использую максимум в диапазоне 2мес.(+/-), хотя кажется он универсальный и работает даже на больших промежутках.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime StartDate = Model.MinDate.Value;
DateTime diff = StartDate.AddDays(((int)DayOfWeek.Sunday - (int)StartDate.DayOfWeek));
double weeks = Math.Ceiling((Model.MaxDate - diff).Value.TotalDays / 7);
```

Как то так получилось.
Отсчет новой недели лучше брать с воскресенья(в формуле переменной `diff`), иначе если брать `ПН` за начало недели, то последний день который выпадает на `ПН` - игнорится.